# How to separate Unit and Functional Tests in Symfony2?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, tdd

I wonder :

1. if **it's a good idea to separate tests** (Unit | 
   Functional ...) in Symfony2,
2. and **how I should separate**:

**By folders structure** :

```
tests 
|-- functional    
|-- unit
```

**By config in phpunit.xml** :

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">...</testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional">...</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

**By annotation**

```
/**
 * @group unit    
 */
 function testMyUnit()
```

Ii it a reasonable approach? Is there a standard way to do this? What "levels" separate (unit > integration > functional)? And how to take advantage of that if I want to play with these tests manually and fastest, and obtain rational coverage reports in Jenkins?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard approach of putting your functional tests in the Controller folder of your bundle?

Comment: Where put integration tests (using kernel, or container for example) or "functional code" out of controller ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go for two configuration files - one for functional and one for unit tests. Then you can run your unit tests separately from functional. You want your unit tests to run as quickly as possible or otherwise nobody's gonna run them at development time, so this approach works quite well.

```
phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml
phpunit -c app/phpunit_functional.xml
```

The directory structures we used:

```
src/Namespace/Bundle/Tests/Unit/
src/Namespace/Bundle/Tests/Functional/
```

The second way is to have one configuration file and run `phpunit --testsuite unit`.

Comment: how does this work across multiple bundles? do i have to update a global phpunit file every time I add/remove a bundle?